# TYPO3 news plugin read whole news not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I'm using TYPO3 7.6.4 with the news plugin

[image]

Now I've got the problem that the link to the news artikle is not working

thats the link typo3 generates:

[image]

When I click the link the detailed page is not loaded ... what could be the problem?

Comment: Probably no single view page is selected in plugin or in typoscript.

Comment: yes your right there is no single view page selected. Can you explain to me what kind of page Id I need?

Comment: do I have to create a single view page for each news entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you need to create 3 pages:

1. A sysfolder which contains the records
2. A page withe plugin and select the "list view". In tab *Additional* and field **PageId for single news display* choose page number 3
3. A page with the plugin and select the "detail view".